# Sequence Function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Problem: What is the close-form/ recursive equation/ generating fucntion  of the following sequence, which has following 256 entries:

1 7 7 7 7 9 9 9 7 9 9 9 7 9 9 9 7 11 11 11 11 13 13 13 11 13 13 13 11 13 13 13 7 11 11 11 11 13 13 13 11 13 13 13 11 13 13 13 7 11 11 11 11 13 13 13 11 13 13 13 11 13 13 13 7 11 11 11 11 13 13 13 11 13 13 13 11 13 13 13 9 13 13 13 13 15 15 15 13 15 15 15 13 15 15 15 9 13 13 13 13 15 15 15 13 15 15 15 13 15 15 15 9 13 13 13 13 15 15 15 13 15 15 15 13 15 15 15 7 11 11 11 11 13 13 13 11 13 13 13 11 13 13 13 9 13 13 13 13 15 15 15 13 15 15 15 13 15 15 15 9 13 13 13 13 15 15 15 13 15 15 15 13 15 15 15 9 13 13 13 13 15 15 15 13 15 15 15 13 15 15 15 7 11 11 11 11 13 13 13 11 13 13 13 11 13 13 13 9 13 13 13 13 15 15 15 13 15 15 15 13 15 15 15 9 13 13 13 13 15 15 15 13 15 15 15 13 15 15 15 9 13 13 13 13 15 15 15 13 15 15 15 13 15 15 15

Origin/background of Problem: These number are generated from a divide and conquer algorithm. For example if we have a 8 bit binary-string and we are asked to find the location of 1's in minimal number of questions then, the above sequence is the # of questions asked for each possible binary 8-bit word i.e from 00000000, 00000001 ....11111111 the corresponding # of questions are elements of above sequence i.e 1,7,..15, respectively.

Algorithm:

1) First question: Is is equal to ZERO (0000 0000) ? The answer is No, for our case.

2) Then divide the original 8 bit word into two 4 bit segments, and again ask the same question for each of the two 4 bit words. So for our case it would be YES for the first segment (0000) and NO for the other segment (0001)?

3) Now, this time I will be questioning only the segment where I got NO. In our case it was 0001. Then, I will now again divide this 4-bit segment into two segments and pose the same question. Hence, is 00 equal to ZERO? answer : YES. For the other segment , 01, the answer is NO.

4) This is the final step. I will again divide the 2-bit word into two 1-bits, i-e 0 and 1. So, my first question is is 0 equal to 0? answer is YES. And for the other remaining bit, is 1 equal to 0? Answer is NO.

So, I asked a total of 7 questions to find the location of 1 in a binary word of 0000 0001. Similarly, we will go through other binary words.

Comment: If you know 01 is not 00, but the first digit is 0, then the second digit must be 1.  Can you shorten the number of questions in this way?

Comment: Write the numbers in base 4; the number of questions depends on which digits if any are zero.  So there are 16 situations.  What does that look like?

Answer (score 1):

Write the number in base 4.  Count the number of nonzero digits.
If there none, it will take 1 question.
If there is one, it will take 7 questions.
If there are three, it will take 13 questions.
If there are four, it will take 15 questions.
If there are two in the same half, it will take 9 questions.
If there are two in opposite halves, it will take 11 questions.

Comment: Well, I will check your answer and get back to you. Thanks. But if someone can find some mathematical equation, that will precisely solve my question.